# How to transfer a webapp to https from the cloudflare?

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, cloudflare

It was not in my plans to install the server as nginx, so my web application is launched on the node.js server. There, similar constructions are used to refer to certain pages:

---

on server:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client', 'dist')))
}
app.use('/api/bonds', bonds);
const port = 80;
```

on client:

```
const url = '1.2.3.4:80/api/bonds';
class BondsService {
    static getBonds() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(url);
                const data = res.data;
                resolve(data.map(bond => ({
                    ...bond
                })));
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        })
    }
```

I transferred my domain to cloudflare, and set the free SSL certificate to flexible mode. When I access the application through http, everything works, but when does the http give such an error:

> xhr.js:178 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://1.2.3.4/api/bonds'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How can you fix it?

Comment: Ideally port 80 is used for http. Can you try not to use this port?

Comment: @rootkonda thanks for the comment, do you suggest using port 443 or any other port at all?

Comment: Where is this service running ? If it is running on example.com itself then just use https://example.com/api/bonds, if not, first check what port is set for https in 1.2.3.4 machine and use that one.

Comment: @rootkonda the service runs on a VPS server, and all calls within the server are exclusively by the server's ip (1.2.3.4), not by the domain name, also firewall is installed on the server, but of course all the necessary ports are open. The scheme of work is vps->cloudflare->domain provider->client

Comment: Ok you can try using 443 if it doesnt work, check the https port set on 1.2.3.4.

Comment: @rootkonda it turned out strangely, now I can connect to the server by 1.2.3.4:443, but the cloudflower stopped seeing it. and the service also not respond with thar error: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" (the empty page was loaded successfully)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219119/discussion-between-rootkonda-and-royalgoose).

Comment: Yes. I already started the chat and msged you

Comment: I dont get any reply in the chat. If this answer resolved the issue you mentioned here then I can post as an answer. At any case, you have to use https port 443 or relevant https port set on 1.2.3.4. The issues which comes after this change has to be debugged separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had an extensive(an hour long) discussion in the chat and I dont know how to refer the chat here entirely.So i am just posting the solution which can help you go in the right direction:

If you are part of organisation then you first have to check with Cloudflare team or whoever is the contact person from infra

1. Connection between browser and cloudfare is https or not ? if its already https then does the CA certificate is already part of the browser/system or do we need to explicitly load it.
2. What about the connection between cloudflare and node.js server - is it encrypted or not...if it is encrypted then you also have to load the certificates of node.js server or cloudflare server's certificates into each other's trust store. This will depend on whether it is mutual TLS or not. If it is going to be http traffic between cloudfare and node.js server then no certificates required.

---

Please get more understanding on https/SSL handshake process to get more clarity.